# How to export a graph png file in R to Amazon S3 cloud storage

Tags: r, amazon-s3

In a VM server environment, my R script needs to export a png file directly to Amazon S3 - does anyone know if there is a way to do it directly in R? (As opposed a separate listener process that picks up new files and moves them to S3 storage).

Comment: If you mount the S3 storage to make it appear as a local drive ...

Comment: Great idea! Do you know if that will work in a remote VM server environment like Heroku?

Comment: Maybe this link provides some information: http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/#scenarios

Comment: @Simon, with the [RAmazonS3](http://www.omegahat.org/RAmazonS3/) package loaded you can directly communicate with S3 storage.

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you. Please submit this as the answer and I will accept it.